# Drupal 7: Webform: Set hidden field to some value on radio button selection

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I have a Webform which has a Selection List of radio buttons on it.

I would like to set the value of a hidden text field based on radio button selection.
So if user selects 1st option i would like the text field to have "First" as text and like that.

can this be done? I want to eventually use this text field later on for other processing.

Comment: Can you just use the value of the radio button selection later on rather than doing this client side?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ben...you should use the value of the select fields themselves using the syntax for the select field Options, ie `"safe_key|Some readable option"` (without quotes)

So your select field options would have something like:

```
first|This is some pizza
second|Just the cheese
```

If you like, since you want the value "First", you can even capitalize the keys, ie:

```
First|This is some pizza
Second|Just the cheese
```

However, if you insist on having the select field change the hidden field's value and you want to do this purely through Drupal 7 front-end, then I suggest the following:

- Install the following module:

  - Code per Node - allows you to add custom CSS/JS to content types or individual nodes
- Update your content type settings (ie. by content types or individual nodes)
- Then, write some jQuery or JS to do what you want on the node that is housing your webform...ie:

Some Javascript::jQuery for what you want:

```
jQuery( "#my-select-field" )
  .change(function () {
    var str = jQuery(this).text();
    jQuery( "my-hidden-field" ).val( str );
  })
  .change();
```

The ".change()" call at the end is to trigger a change event so that your hidden field is always populated with the appropriate data...

Be sure to put your code in a `"jQuery( document ).ready(function() { ... }"` call so that the bind is made at the right moment and so your page has finished loading.

*Note: In Drupal 7, the core jQuery Library is referenced by `"jQuery"`, not the `"$"` alias

Comment: I agree that setting the Select values is the sane way to go. But if you are committed to using a second field and you are comfortable with a custom module, rather than using jQuery I suggest using hook_form_submit to set the value of the hidden field. Then you don't worry about people with JavaScript turned off or any other client-side issues.

Comment: Thanks Graham. Can you tell me about how to use hook_form_submit? I am really new to Drupal and thus any help would be great !!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a module that implements a submit function. So if your module is "specialFormProcessing" you would create the function:

```
function specialFormProcessing_mySubmitFunction($form, &$form_state) {
}
```

Within that function, you would set the value of the hidden field from the SELECT box.

You should also add your function to the array of functions that will process the form. There will be yours and the form's original submit function (depending upon what the form is), and maybe others that other modules have implemented. You do this by creating a hook_form_alter() function in your module:

```
function specialFormProcessing_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
}
```

You use the $form_id to make sure you are working on the correct form, then do something like:

```
$form['#submit'][]='specialFormProcessing_mySubmitFunction';
```

I found the book "Pro Drupal Development" by VanDyk very helpful when I was learning Drupal and manipulating Forms. I was using Drupal 6, but he has a newer edition for Drupal 7. There are criticisms that it doesn't deal with some of the new Drupal 7 features, but its treatment of Forms should be good.